# How to add asp.net Webform to an existing MVC 2 project

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, report-viewer2010

Is there a way to add asp.net webform to mvc 2 project.

I need to do that because mvc dosen't support ReportViewer control.

Thanks.

My Config: 
IIS 7, Asp.Net MVC2, framework 4.0 , Entity Framework.